# How to execute a IronPython script on click chart elements in Python?

Tags: spotfire

Is it possible to call a script in Python when a chart in Spotfire is clicked? How to do that?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Deploying package files onto the server](https://community.tibco.com/wiki/how-deploy-custom-python-modules-use-tibco-spotfirer-clients)

[Trigger the script](https://community.tibco.com/questions/trigger-script-when-marking-rows-without-terrtsss)

Comment: use caution with `setInterval()`. it creates a timer but does not destroy it when you navigate away, which can create multiple instances of your `setInterval()` function all competing with one another (also hi @scsimon! :)